# using $obj -> get_content tag comes up with an error

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP and MySQL I am trying to build my own CMS but when following a tutorial I got this code

on a cms_class.php

```
 <?php
 class modernCMS{ //starts class
  var $host;
 var $username;
 var $password;
 var $db;
 function connect(){
          $con=     mysql_connect(    $this    ->    host, $this->username, $this->password);
    mysql_select_db($this->db, $con) or die (mysql_error()) ;
}// ends function 

function get_content(){
    $query= "SELECT * 
FROM cms_content ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result= mysql_query($$query);

    while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        echo '<h1>' . $row['title'] . '</h1>';
        echo '<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>';
    }
 }

 } //Ends class

?>
```

then on my index page i have  (php first)

```
 <?php 

include '_class/cms_class.php';

$obj= new modernCMS();

//set up connection variables
$obj->host='localhost';
$obj->username='root';
$obj->password='';
$obj->db='modernCMS';

//Connection to the DB

$obj->connect();


?>
```

then the php to get the content from my cms_content table is

```
<?=$obj-> get_content()?>
```

when ran on my local host server I get these errors....

> undefined variable cms_class.php line 18 mysql_fetch_assoc()

modernCMS-> get_content on my index.php line 34

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1):

In your `get_content` function you create the variable `$result` but then pass the variable `$res` to `mysql_fetch_assoc` which doesn't exist.  You also had double `$$` on `$query` in your call to `mysql_query` which I removed too.

```
function get_content(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cms_content ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<h1>' . $row['title'] . '</h1>';
        echo '<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>';
    }
 }
```